# Where to see print statements or find outputs generated in Docker container?

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

In my `docker-compose.yaml` I am booting up Apache Pulsar's standalone environment and then running some python scripts to write an `output.txt` and `print` some text.

Normally if I run this locally, the `print` statements go to the terminal and the `output.txt` gets written and saved at the parent directory. But when I run this process with my `docker-compose.yaml` nothing gets printed because my terminal is now dedicated to the status updates since both images are meant to persist.

So where do I see my output files and print statements to determine I'm getting the expected behavior?

Comment: I have this same scenario and i write logs to syslog

Comment: If you don't run docker compose in daemon mode then the logs from your containers will be output to your terminal. If running inn daemon mode you can use `docker-compose logs <service>` to get the logs from a particular service

Comment: by default, it will be write on your ```WORKDIR``` folder stated on your dockerfile. about the output, it is inside the dockerization, so you can't see it unless you select the ```-d``` option to run your docker image

Answer (score 1):

For the files, I would recommend you add a volume mount to the container, and write out the files in that location in the container. Then you can access them as you would any other file locally.

For the `print` statements, `docker-compose logs` should let you view the output from the containers.